# Hive CASE or IF/ELSE statement usage to perform another operation inside WHEN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

The problem statement is related to hive as follows :

I need to decrypt column values which are encrypted values but few values in the column are either null or not encrypted(by mistake).

I am using below WHEN clause but that only tells me which encrypted value is valid and which is not.
What I want to achieve is, only valid keys should be a part of the select statement without any nulls and non encrypted values as that is resulting into garbage values after decryption.

sample code :

```
 

    SELECT
      a.abc,
      a.mno,
      a.xyz,
     CASE
      WHEN a.xyz rlike '=' THEN xyz
      ELSE 'Key Incorrect'
     END as Result,
      DECRYPT(STRING(b.decryptid),
        STRING(xyz)) AS xyz_decrypted
    FROM
      db.a a
    LEFT JOIN
      b
    ON
      (a.abc = b.def) limit 10;
```

As show above, what I need is :

WHEN a.xyz rlike '=' THEN **DECRYPT(STRING(b.decrypclientid.decryptclientid),STRING(xyz)) AS xyz_decrypted**

But I do not think it is possible. please help with a solution to this query.

Note : All encrypted values have '=' in them and that is how we identify if it is an actual valid key.

and DECRYPT(STRING(b.decryptid), STRING(xyz)) is applying the decryptid as the key to decrypt the encrypted value(xyz)

Comment: You can't refer to a column alias in the same `SELECT` list. So either use a subquery, or repeat the `CASE` expression in the argument to `DECRYPT()`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar . I was able to solve it!

Comment: can you pls share the solution and close this qn

Comment: Sure, the solution was :

WHEN a.xyz LIKE '%=%'  THEN DECRYPT(STRING(b.decryptclientid), STRING(a.xyz))  
  ELSE a.xyz
END as xyz_decrypted,